# What is the correct way to send Markdown code via the API?

Tags: block-editor, visual-editor, markdown

When I send Markdown via the API, the Gutenberg editor adds the content within the Classic Editor block.

The only way that Gutenberg accepts it using its native blocks is if I sent it by converting Markdown to something like this:

`<!-- wp:paragraph --><p>This is a test.</p><!-- /wp:paragraph -->`

Even when I sent the HTML like this:

`<p>This is a test.</p>`, it still added it within the Classic Editor.

When I pasted my Markdown code directly into Gutenberg, it did accept it without any issues.

Is there a correct way to send Markdown via the API?

Comment: Can you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Otherwise it's hard to see what you're talking about and what may be going wrong.